# Why automatically select current date time? How can I stop this automatic selection of current data time? How can I get only year?

Tags: bootstrap-4, datepicker

I need to select only year. And I have use datepicker to get only year. but while I select any year it automatic select current date time.

I have include.  Bootstrap 4.2 cdn for js and css, bootstrap-datepicker 1.9 for css and js, jQuery 3.3.1

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
```

jQuery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('body').on('focus',".datepicker", function(){
        if( $(this).hasClass('hasDatepicker') === false )  {
            $(this).datepicker({
                minViewMode: 2,
                format: 'yyyy'
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you add a minimal, verifiable, complete example which replicates this issue... that'll make it much easier to help

Comment: Thanks for your afford. I solved it. There was a problem with same class name that is why it automatically shows me current date.